# ftp not retrieving my directory file ,anyone have solution?

Tags: ftp

i am trying to retrieving the directory of my site but i am not getting it clearly what is happening ,why it not retrieving my directory,please anyone can help to solve it,i am showing an image of ftp response what i am getting,
and also want to ask what is `200 port` means and what is `425 could not open data to`port 16294`?

[image]

Comment: FTP uses two connections: a command connection and a separate data connection. PORT tells the server (I think) the address to connect back to, and 200 is FTP's 'success' status code (just like HTTP). Note that this is a 192.168.x.x address, which is an internal range, and so the server can't actually connect to this. Chances are this is your address on an internal network, not your external IP address. Try using passive FTP mode if you can, where your client is responsible for establishing the data connection not vice versa. And nowadays you should probably be using secure FTP or SCP anyway.

Comment: But if you're still having problems then this is probably one for your web host not us - we can offer general FTP advice and explanation, but if something more complex is going wrong you'll need to ask them.